# Generating infinite prime number squence using generators

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to generate an infinite prime number sequence using  sieve of Eratosthenes. This is the code:

```
def naturals()->int:
    '''Generate natural numbers indefinitely'''
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i
        i = i+1

def primes():
    N = naturals()
    _ = next(N)#Pop out 1
    while True:
        n = next(N)
        yield n
        N = (i for i in N if i%n != 0)
```

However, the generator above simply yields 2,3,4... So where exactly did I go wrong?

Comment: You have to record existing prime factors somewhere. While I understand your attempt, out would be very inefficient if it worked.

Comment: Even if you got this working, it wouldn't be the sieve of Eratosthenes. It would be trial division. A real sieve of Eratosthenes does not involve divisibility tests.

Comment: @Kevin: The generators never need to use the `N` variable after creation, though. Reassigning `n` is a bigger problem.

Comment: Actually, I implemented this looking at a computerphile video that implemented this in Haskell. Either I understood it wrong or they were wrong to call it sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: `naturals` is just `itertools.count`

Comment: @p.shreyasshetty: The guy in the video got it wrong. See https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping through one step at a time:

```
while True:
    n = next(N)
```

`n` is 2.

```
    yield n
    N = (i for i in N if i%n != 0)
```

This wraps `N` in a generator which removes values that are multiples of `n`.  Note that we said multiples of **`n`**, not multiples of 2.

On the next loop, we grab the next element out of `naturals()`, getting 3, modulus it against `n`, which is 2, and get 1, which is not zero.  So we assign 3 to n and yield it.  We then wrap the previous `N` in another generator which does the same thing as the previous wrapper did, which slows it down but has no other effect.

Then, on the next loop, we grab the next element out of `naturals()`, getting 4, modulus it against `n`, which is 3, and get 1, which is not zero.  Then we do the modulus again and get the same result.  So we assign 4 to `n` and yield it...

Comment: So the actual problem lies in reassigning n?

Comment: The problem is that you are not creating a new variable on each iteration, just reusing the same variable.  However, you are also likely to see very poor performance from this method, because unwinding all of the generators takes time.

Comment: Also because it's trial division, and because it doesn't even stop the trial division at the square root of whatever number it's testing, and because the giant stack of generators is going to hit the recursion limit after about 1000 primes.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you're satisfied with successive division checks, you can implement the more common version:

- Initialize your sequence with 2
- Starting with 3 and checking only odd numbers ...
- If `N` isn't divisible by any existing prime,
- ... add it to the list of primes and emit it.
- increment `N` by 2.

Code in your styling:

```
def primes():
    sofar = [2]
    n = 3
    yield 2

    while True:
        if all(n%i for i in sofar):
            sofar.append(n)
            yield n
        n += 2
```

This slows down to 100 primes / sec around N = 250,000 and continues to degrade from there.

Comment: BTW, I sped this up a *lot* by maintaining two lists: one with all the primes <= sqrt(n), and a second with the larger primes.   When I increment `n`, I check to see whether I need to move the lowest prime in the second list into the "check" list.